# Fatou's lemma assuming convergence in measure

Tags: measure-theory

On the web, I have not found much concerning the argument which is convincing to me. I have then worked out a proof of Fatou's Lemma assuming convergence in measure. I ask you if it sounds fine. Thank you so much.

[image]